# Sequelize, how to retrieve specific fields from joined tables

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have:

```
db.Animal.findAll({ attributes: ['id', 'name'], include: [db.Age] }).success(function(results) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(results));
});
```

It gives me the fields ID and NAME from table Animal... but I also want to get specific fields from table Age and not all the fields (this is how it is working right now).

What can I do?

Answer (score 7):

You can specify attributes within the include array. Try rearranging like so:

```
db.Animal.findAll({ attributes: ['id', 'name'], 
  include: [{ model: db.Age, attributes: ['field1'] }]
})
.success(function(res){ console.log( JSON.stringify(res) ) })
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this to get a user and his note information (I also filtered the data I got using attributes):

```
const user = await User.findByPk(userId, {
  attributes: ['id', 'name'],
  include: [{ model: Note, attributes: ['id', 'title', 'content'] }],
});
```